# How to escape quotes in a smali string

Tags: android, escaping, smali, apktool

I have the following smali code that executes a binary file on Android with su priviledges:

```
    [...]
    .line 66
    invoke-static {}, Ljava/lang/Runtime;->getRuntime()Ljava/lang/Runtime;

    move-result-object v6

    const-string v7, "su -c /system/bin/screencap -p /data/local/tmp/x.png"

    invoke-virtual {v6, v7}, Ljava/lang/Runtime;->exec(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Process;
    [...]
```

I need to set a part of the string in quotes, like so:

```
'su -c "/system/bin/screencap -p /data/local/tmp/x.png"'
```

How can I escape the quotes? I tried with backslashes but apktool complains about it when trying to rebuild the APK file.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: backslashes are the correct way to escape this. If that's not working for you, please include the actual error :)

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to escape the embedded double quotes with a backslash, the same as java.

```
const-string v7, "su -c \"/system/bin/screencap -p /data/local/tmp/x.png\""
```